# Ubuntu 16.04 touchscreen problem

Tags: drivers, usb, mouse, touchscreen

I have information kiosk with touchscreen. It's working fine under Windows, but isn't work under linux.

dmesg on insert usb from touch

```
[ 2548.828917] usb 1-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 5
[ 2604.346673] usb 1-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[ 2604.460153] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=10c4, idProduct=8001
[ 2604.460157] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2604.460160] usb 1-1.4: Product:                       
[ 2604.460162] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer:                 
[ 2604.460164] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: 2011_01_05_00000001
[ 2604.467456] hid-multitouch 0003:10C4:8001.0003: ignoring exceeding usage max
[ 2604.467591] hid-multitouch 0003:10C4:8001.0003: ignoring exceeding usage max
[ 2604.468960] input:                                         as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/0003:10C4:8001.0003/input/input15
[ 2604.469321] hid-multitouch 0003:10C4:8001.0003: input,hiddev1,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [                                       ] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.4/input0
```

udevadm monitor

```
KERNEL[2603.615756] add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[2603.620621] add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/0003:10C4:8001.0003 (hid)
KERNEL[2603.622410] add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/0003:10C4:8001.0003/input/input15 (input)
KERNEL[2603.622493] add  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/0003:10C4:8001.0003/input/input15/mouse0 (input)
KERNEL[2603.622594] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/0003:10C4:8001.0003/input/input15/event4 (input)
KERNEL[2603.622729] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/usbmisc/hiddev1 (usbmisc)
KERNEL[2603.622775] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/0003:10C4:8001.0003/hidraw/hidraw1 (hidraw)
UDEV  [2603.626954] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4 (usb)
UDEV  [2603.628312] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [2603.629549] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/0003:10C4:8001.0003 (hid)
UDEV  [2603.630041] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/usbmisc/hiddev1 (usbmisc)
UDEV  [2603.631468] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/0003:10C4:8001.0003/hidraw/hidraw1 (hidraw)
UDEV  [2603.631699] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/0003:10C4:8001.0003/input/input15 (input)
UDEV  [2603.633982] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/0003:10C4:8001.0003/input/input15/mouse0 (input)
UDEV  [2603.716784] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/0003:10C4:8001.0003/input/input15/event4 (input)
```

Then i use cat for /dev/hidraw1 i got an events on output then touch to touchscreen

```
sudo cat /dev/hidraw1
```

but then I try to cat /dev/input/mouse0 or /dev/input/event4 I got nothing then touch the screen. 
udevadm output

```
sudo udevadm info --attribute-walk /dev/input/mouse0

looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/0003:10C4:8001.0003/input/input15/mouse0':
KERNEL=="mouse0"
SUBSYSTEM=="input"
DRIVER==""

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/0003:10C4:8001.0003/input/input15':
KERNELS=="input15"
SUBSYSTEMS=="input"
DRIVERS==""
ATTRS{name}=="                                       "
ATTRS{phys}=="usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.4/input0"
ATTRS{properties}=="2"
ATTRS{uniq}=="2011_01_05_00000001"

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/0003:10C4:8001.0003':
KERNELS=="0003:10C4:8001.0003"
SUBSYSTEMS=="hid"
DRIVERS=="hid-multitouch"
ATTRS{country}=="21"
ATTRS{quirks}=="4112"

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0':
KERNELS=="1-1.4:1.0"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
DRIVERS=="usbhid"
ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="03"
ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="00"
ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="00"
ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="02"
ATTRS{interface}=="MULTI_DEV"
ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4':
KERNELS=="1-1.4"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
DRIVERS=="usb"
ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="128mA"
ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0000"
ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
ATTRS{configuration}=="MULTI_CONFIG"
ATTRS{devnum}=="6"
ATTRS{devpath}=="1.4"
ATTRS{idProduct}=="8001"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="10c4"
ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
ATTRS{manufacturer}=="                "
ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
ATTRS{product}=="                      "
ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
ATTRS{removable}=="removable"
ATTRS{serial}=="2011_01_05_00000001"
ATTRS{speed}=="12"
ATTRS{urbnum}=="18"
ATTRS{version}==" 1.10"

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1':
KERNELS=="1-1"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
DRIVERS=="usb"
ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0000"
ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
ATTRS{configuration}==""
ATTRS{devnum}=="2"
ATTRS{devpath}=="1"
ATTRS{idProduct}=="0024"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="8087"
ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
ATTRS{maxchild}=="4"
ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
ATTRS{removable}=="fixed"
ATTRS{speed}=="480"
ATTRS{urbnum}=="70"
ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
```

Can somebody help make it works?

Comment: I also have the same problem. Have you solved it?